# Seperate comma separated mySql database field value with php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

If you believe this is a duplicate please let me now as I'm not totally sure what to search for to check, (I will remove if duplicate)

I have a list of of numbers in a mySql field called sess_times in a table called test_sess, the numbers for the first row are:

25, 38, 40, 50

is it possible to split these into php variable e.g:

```
$no1 = 25
$no2 = 38
$no3 = 40
$no4 = 50
```

I'm trying to put the individual numbers in a table, something like below:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td><?php echo $no1; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td><?php echo $no2; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 3 </td>
    <td><?php echo $no3; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 4 </td>
    <td><?php echo $no4; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any help with this would be great so thanks in advance for any answers.

HERE'S THE SOLUTION I USED, A COMBINATION OF 2 ANSWERS BELOW:

```
$data = '25,38,40,50';
$string = explode(",", $data);
$number = 0;
echo '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">';
for($i=0; $i<count($string); $i++)
{
    $number = $number +1;
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>' . $number . '</td>
            <td>' . $string[$i] . '</td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
```

Comment: The `$number = $number +1;` is pointless, you have that in `$i+1` (see my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP's `explode` function.

When you output everything, save it into a variable.

Then, `$string = explode(",", $string);` will produce this:

`Array ( [0] => 28[1] => 38 [2] => 40 [3] => 50 )`

To output this, you can then use `$string[number]` for each value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems like the best example for me to manipulate the data in multiple html table

Answer (score 3):

You can [explode](http://php.net/explode) them

```
$string="25,38,40,50";
$numbers=explode(",",$string);
print_r($numbers); // You can use them for printing like echo $numbers[0]; or 1 or 2 or 3
```

And if you don't want the result in an array and still want those 4 variable names you can do this

```
$string="25,38,40,50";
list($no1,$no2,$no3,$no4)=explode(",",$string);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't see the second part before, I'll try this out

Comment: Another issue I have is that the number of numbers could be anything so I would know it is 4 variables

Comment: Then go for the array option listed in the answer. Then you can access all those values by  `$numbers[0]` or `$numbers[1]` etc.

Answer (score 2):

This would give you the table output and it doesn't require the total amount to be known.

```
$data = '25,38,40,50';

$arr = explode(',', $data);

echo '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">';
for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++)
{
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>' . $i+1 . '</td>
            <td>' . $arr[$i] . '</td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode();`

ex:

```
$numbers='25,38,40,50';
$numbers_array= explode(",", $no);
foreach($numbers_array as $key => $number)
{
    $var_name='no'.(++$key);
    $$var_name=$number;
}

echo $no1.'<br>;
echo $no2.'<br>;
echo $no3.'<br>;
echo $no4.'<br>;
```