# How to find values in range in comma seperated field MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have database design like below for `product table`.

```
+-------+-----------+
| ID    |     Size  |
+-------+-----------+
| 1     |    1,2,4  |
| 2     |    2,6,8  |
| 3     |    3,7,9  |
| 4     |    5,8,11 |
```

Now I want id for size between two values.

For example I need product size between 5 to 8 then it should return 2,3,4 row.

Can anyone guide me how to do it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume normalizing the database is not an option?

Comment: You need to clarify on this more. What exactly do you want?

Comment: I'm sorry, but comma separated values are not what relational databases work well with. To get any kind of performance (or simplicity for that matter) out of this query, you'll need to change your data model.

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040128/seperate-comma-seperated-mysql-database-field-value-with-php?rq=1)

Comment: Actually i want products in between range of size with this database structure.

Comment: You mean all the size between 2 & 5 ,Well can we see what have you tried yet ?

Comment: Your example is not clear please specify exactly what you want or give some more examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find yourself in a situation like that you have painted yourself in a corner. First approach would be to split the CSV in single column into a more reasonable layout; for example:

```
+----+------+
| ID | Size |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  1 |    2 |
|  1 |    4 |
|  2 |    2 |
|  2 |    6 |
|  2 |    8 |
and so on...
```

I understand that in real life this may not always be possible and in that case you need a bit less sophisticated approach. If the ranges you search for a limited in size you could use [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) to solve this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE findsetrange (IN a INT, IN b INT)
BEGIN
 DECLARE i INT;

 DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS fsr_temp;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE fsr_temp (id int);

 SET i=a;

 WHILE (i<=b) DO

  INSERT INTO fsr_temp (id) VALUES (i);

  SET i=i+1;
 END WHILE;

 DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS fsr_res;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE fsr_res 
  SELECT ProductTable.* FROM ProductTable
   JOIN (
     SELECT DISTINCT ProductTable.id 
      FROM fsr_temp 
      JOIN ProductTable ON (find_in_set(fsr_temp.id,ProductTable.a))
     ) as p ON (p.id=ProductTable.id);

 DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS fsr_temp;

 SELECT * FROM fsr_res;

END
```

This stored procedure can then be called to retrieve range as needed. To match your question you could use

```
CALL findsetrange(5,8);
```

Which will return:

```
+-------+-----------+
| ID    |     Size  |
+-------+-----------+
| 2     |    2,6,8  |
| 3     |    3,7,9  |
| 4     |    5,8,11 |
+-------+-----------+
```

Single values can be returned by repeating the value twice:

```
CALL findsetrange(7,7);

+-------+-----------+
| ID    |     Size  |
+-------+-----------+
| 3     |    3,7,9  |
+-------+-----------+
```

Currently result set is left in temporary table `fsr_res` which you can use on further queries.